# Having an error when you import a python module if the python script is runned in a php file

Tags: php, python, python-module

I used this [script](http://blog.idealmind.com.br/php/how-to-execute-python-script-from-php-and-show-output-on-browser/) for running a python script in php in localhost but it does not read modules like numpy and cv2.

Through PHP i got the usual error when it not read a module:

```
 import numpy as np ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I moved the python file in the python folder C:\Python27 and does not change anything!
If i use the Python Shell it works!

Maybe it is an apache problem?

Here, the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Script Python Example
import time
import sys
import numpy as np


print "Initializing Python Script"

print "The passed arguments are ", sys.argv

print "Writing lines to a file"

ifile = open( "/tmp/testfile", "w+")
for i in range(0,100):
 ifile.write( "One of the lines of the filen" )
 print "Printing line ",i," to /tmp/testfile"

ifile.close()

print "Reading and printing lines of /tmp/testfile"
ifile = open( "/tmp/testfile", "r")
for line in ifile:
 print line
ifile.close()
print "End of Python Script"
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$param1 = "first";
$param2 = "second";
$param3 = "third";

$command = "python /home/wellington/python_script_example.py";
$command .= " $param1 $param2 $param3 2>&1";

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
echo "<style type='text/css'>
 body{
 background:#000;
 color: #7FFF00;
 font-family:'Lucida Console',sans-serif !important;
 font-size: 12px;
 }
 </style>";

$pid = popen( $command,"r");

echo "<body><pre>";
while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
 echo fread($pid, 256);
 flush();
 ob_flush();
 echo "<script>window.scrollTo(0,99999);</script>";
 usleep(100000);
}
pclose($pid);

echo "</pre><script>window.scrollTo(0,99999);</script>";
echo "<br /><br />Script finalizado<br /><br />";
?>
```

Comment: Do you have Numpy installed? What does `find / -iname '*numpy*'` output?

Comment: It is installed, because if i run the script via python shell it works!

Comment: i checked also the pythonpath and is ok C:/Python2.7/Lib/site-packages/

Comment: I solved i change my PYTHONPATH now i got another error:   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 128, in 
    from version import git_revision as __git_revision__
ImportError: No module named version